# java how to parse xml and save data into mysql database

Tags: java, sql, xml, jaxb, sax

I have a question.

I want to parse XML file using SAX or JAXB and save the parsed file into a database using java, any help please.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please visit the [help] and also read [ask] to understand what types of questions are on-topic here.  Your question, which shows no effort or any attempt to solve the problem, is considered off-topic.  There are many tutorials available on the web describing how to parse XML in java, and StackOverflow is not a tutorial or "write my code for me" site.

Answer (score 2):

Even though you should research the topic first, I am giving you a starting point. Basically you'd use unmarshalling to create a java object from an XML (see http://lstierneyltd.com/blog/development/examples/java-to-xml-xml-to-java-marshalling-and-unmarshalling/). Then you could use some i.e. Apache Cayenne or Hibernate to store the object to a database.

I would recommend to refrain from putting the XML to a relational database itself if you expect significant amounts of data.